# Public calendar with mail notification

Tags: calendar

I am searching an online public calendar service which contains some features of Google Calendar for my sports club. They need to manage multiple calendars (for example: for special events, regular training days, a calendar for the chairman, finance etc.). The events of each calendar should have different colors to make everything a bit ordered. Some calendars can be shared to all club members and are public available (the calendars for the regular training days and special events). It has to be really easy for the members to see these calendars in one overview (so it should not be mandatory to import the calendar in your own Google Calendar before seeing an overview).

Some calendars should not be public available, but only available for a certain group of people. Members should also be able to subscribe to the public calendars, they now should get mail notifications when an event is added or updated.

The events should contain information like: Title, description, location and (of course) date and time. Does a service which fulfills this requirements exists?

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand what Google Calendar does not have in your requests... As for the importing into your own calendar, you don't need to as long as you share with 'people who don't use Google Calendar'. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe there's a misunderstanding of the word 'import', and the OP does not even want to set up the sharing links in users calendars. @ObAt, can you edit?

Comment: @JanDoggen is right. The members of the club should be able to view the calendar on a website without configuring something. Another thing I miss in Google Calendar the possibility for me to subscribe to a public calendar and get mail notifications when something is added/edited.

Comment: @Obat please [edit](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/7323/edit) that into your post. If another user asks clarification it means your original question needs improvement.

Comment: Google calendar has a no login option.  After setting public view permissions, click drop (on the correct calendar) and select **share**.  Then **calendar details** and then find the section called **embed this calendar**.  Copy this code into the website where you want and your done.